# Python: sort a list of tuples in a specific order

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of tuples that can be ordered in a variety of ways. For example it can look like this:

```
data = [ ("name", "Derek Carr"),
         ("college", "Fresno State"),
         ("jersey", 4),
         ("team", "Oakland Raiders") ]
```

Or like this:

```
data = [ ("college", "Fresno State"),
         ("jersey", 4),
         ("name", "Derek Carr"),
         ("team", "Oakland Raiders") ]
```

The contents are the same every time but the order of the tuples are different. How can I create a new list that looks exactly like this every time:

```
condensed_data = ["Derek Carr", "Oakland_Raiders"]
```

EDIT: (1) Data list fixed. (2) The reason these lists having varying order is because they're constructed from dictionaries

Comment: Your data isn't valid python syntax ...

Comment: Also, this problem is very straight-forward assuming you actually do have a list of tuples.  Is there a specific part of this problem that you're having trouble with?  Can you show us what you've tried so that we can figure out what is giving you trouble here and hopefully explain it to you so you understand (rather than just handing you some code that you might not understand?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of tuples:

```
[v for key in ["name", "team"] for k, v in data if k == key]
# ['Derek Carr', 'Oakland Raiders']
```

---

Or you can use normal loops:

```
lst = []
for key in ['name', 'team']:
    for k, v in data:
        if k == key:
            lst.append(v)

lst
# ['Derek Carr', 'Oakland Raiders']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. How would I write this if I wasn't allowed to use list comprehensions (e.g. nested iterations)?

Comment: That sounds like an odd constraint, but surely you can write a double loop or construct a dictionary from data and get the value by key.

Comment: It's not a constraint. I'm just curious how it would be done but I'm having trouble figuring it out. But thanks for the edit! I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean your data looks like this:

```
people = [
          [("name", "Derek Carr"),
           ("college", "Fresno State"),
           ("jersey", 4),
           ("team", "Oakland Raiders")],
          [("college", "Fresno State"),
           ("jersey", 4),
           ("name", "Derek Carr"),
           ("team", "Oakland Raiders")]
         ]
```

That is, you have a list of lists, each of which contains **valid** tuples (your examples were not valid Python).

First, we're going to convert each list of tuples into a dictionary mapping keys to values:

```
data = map(dict, people)
```

Now, we can extract just the information you want per person:

```
for p in data:
    p_data = [p["name"], p["team"]]
```

---

If you want to do this for only one person:

```
data = [("name", "Derek Carr"),
        ("college", "Fresno State"),
        ("jersey", 4),
        ("team", "Oakland Raiders")]
person_data = dict(data)
result = [person_data["name"], person_data["team"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good primer on how to sort in python: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting.

The `condensed_data` you have though does not have all the entries? If you're looking to get only the condensed data, you might want to try a list comprehension, such as:

```
condensed_data = sorted([item[1] for item in data if item[1] in ('Derek Carr', 'Oakland Raiders')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare the first part of your tuple (or dict) with `"name"` and `"team"` and if it matches then insert the second part into your `condensed_data`. No need to sort anything here.

For example:

```
res = [None, None]

for tup in data:
    if tup[0] == 'name':
        res[0] = tup[1]
    elif tup[0] == 'team':
        res[1] = tup[1]

>>> print(res)
['Derek Carr', 'Oakland Raiders']
```